# Elasticsearch multi index filter

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

I have 2 indexes, one that stores *users* and one that stores *articles*.

User document:

```
{
  "id" : "152ce52d-e975-4ebd-849a-0a12f535e644",
  "email": "bob@email.com",
  ...
}
```

Index mapping:

```
{
  "mapping": {
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "email": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Article document:

```
{
  "articleId" : "002ce52d-e975-4ebd-849a-0a12f535a536",
  "userId": "152ce52d-e975-4ebd-849a-0a12f535e644",
  ...
}
```

Index mapping:

```
{
  "mapping": {
    "properties": {
      "articleId": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "userId": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to create a *multi index query* that returns all the users that have no article.

I can't figure out how to exclude from the first index items contained in the second index and having the same id/userId field.

Let's say I have the following users and articles:

Users:

```
 [
        {
            "id": "user1",
            "email": "bob@email.com"
        },
        {
            "id": "user2",
            "email": "john@email.com"
        },
        {
            "id": "user3",
            "email": "tom@email.com"
        },
        {
            "id": "user4",
            "email": "ben@email.com"
        }
    ]
```

Articles:

```
[
    {
        "articleId": "id1",
        "userId": "user1"
    },
    {
        "articleId": "id1",
        "userId": "user2"
    }
]
```

As a result of the query I want to have all the users that have no articles:

```
      [{
            "id": "user3",
            "email": "tom@email.com"
        },
        {
            "id": "user4",
            "email": "ben@email.com"
      }]
```

Comment: can you please share your index mapping and sample expected search result?

Comment: @Bhavya Edited the description with index mappings en expected result, thanks!

Comment: What you want to do is something like a JOIN Query in SQL, this is not supported in elasticsearch. You will need two queries, one to get the ids of the users that have articles, and another one to exclude those users that have this same id in your users index. Another option is to denormalize your data and have just one index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @leandrojmp pointed out, you are trying to achieve something like a JOIN Query in SQL where you want to returns all the remaining records from one index, that did not match records from the second index. Refer to this documentation, to know more about [joining queries in elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/joining-queries.html)

> I can't figure out how to exclude from the first index items contained
> in the second index and having the same id/userId field.

**You can use [`_index field`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index-field.html) when performing queries across multiple indexes.**

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "id": "user1"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "id": "user2"
                }
              }
            ],
            "must": {
              "term": {
                "_index": "64469393user"
              }
            }
          }
        },
       {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "userId": "user1"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "userId": "user2"
                }
              }
            ],
            "must": {
              "term": {
                "_index": "64469393article"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "64469393user",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "id": "user3",
          "email": "tom@email.com"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "64469393user",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "id": "user4",
          "email": "ben@email.com"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks @Bhavya. In this case I would need to know the ids beforehand in order to add them in the query. Would it be a different case if the query was "get all the users that haven't written article  with id = id1?

Comment: @Maucan feel free to ask a new question, with your use case as mentioned in the comments above  , And please don't forget to upvote my answer as well 